# Pythonic method for increment lists so a for loop can iterate through

Tags: python

I have the following code (which runs perfectly):

```
shifts = []
for dateitem in pd.date_range(str(beginning_date), str(end_date)).to_list():
    day_shift = datetime.strftime(dateitem, format="%Y%m%d") + "0"
    night_shift = datetime.strftime(dateitem, format="%Y%m%d") + "1"
    shifts.append(day_shift)
    shifts.append(night_shift)

for shift in shifts:
    the_loop_is = str('working_as_is' + shift)
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to write this in order to still be functional?

Thanx

Comment: Please provide some sample input and expected output

Comment: `shifts = [datetime.strftime(dateitem, format="%Y%m%d")+str(i) for dateitem in pd.date_range(str(beginning_date), str(end_date)).to_list() for i in [0, 1]]`? Are you sure you want to use `.to_list()`? Because I think it's already iterable

Comment: end_date = 20191225, beginning_date=20191215. A day shift: 201912150 while a night shift: 201912151. I need to create these shifts between a date range.. (the current works but will give the output in a list ex [201912150,201912151,201912160,.....]. This list is being iterated through because for each shift I need to perform simple functions.. My question is, is there a more pythionic way of writing this (because it does work, I need to 'show some skill' with my current project haha)

Comment: Yes I need to use to_list() for other purposes.

Comment: "need to use `to_list()` for other purposes": such as? That list has no references to it, so it disappears after the for loop completes. Iterating over the `date_range` objects is *identical* to iterating over the anonymous list.